# Matching Two Lists in python with same index no

Tags: python

```
def compare(a,b):
    if a == b:
        return True
    else:
        return False

While(f == 0):

    if(compare(newk1,k1)==True): 
        if(compare(newk2,k2)==True):
            f=1
            break
        else:
            f=0
    else:
       f = 0
    k1 = newk1
    k2 = newk2
```

Error

```
File "C:\Users\..\Desktop\problem_solution.py", line 101, in <module> if(compare(newk1,k1)==True):
File "C:\Users\..\Desktop\problem_solution.py", line 25, in compare if a == b:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Please show your effort

Comment: for i in range(0,3):
        if i in newk1 and i in k1: 
            if newk1.index(i) == k1.index(i):
                //do stuff

Comment: @ShreyGupta edit your question with what youve tried, not in a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for i in range(0,len(k1)):

```
if(newk1[i] == k1[i]).all
    return True
else:
    return False
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

No need to complicate things:

```
if list1 == list2:
    print "Equal"
else:
    print "Not equal"
```